# How to transfer date selection from calendar widget to QLineEdit

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qcalendarwidget

I'm playing around with PyQt5 (which I just started learning yesterday).

I'm trying to create a window/layout, with two entry boxes (to enter 'start' and 'end' dates), so that when each one is clicked, the `QCalendarWidget` is triggered to popup, and when the user selects the date, the date is entered into the `QLineEdit` field.

So far, it simply shows a blank window, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
class selectedDate(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(selectedDate, self).__init__()
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.selection = QLineEdit("Click to Enter Date", self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.selection)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.selection)
        self.selection.installEventFilter(self)


    def mousePressEvent(self, e):
        self.myCal()
        super(selectedDate, self).mousePressEvent(e)

    def eventFilter(self, object, e):
        if self.layout.indexOf(object) != -1:
            if e.type() == e.MouseButtonPress:
                pass

        return super(selectedDate, self).eventFilter(object, e)



    def myCal(self):
        self.cal = QCalendarWidget(self)
        self.cal.setGridVisible(True)
        self.cal.move(10, 20)
        self.cal.clicked[QDate].connect(self.showDate)

        self.date = self.cal.selectedDate()
        self.selection.setText(self.date.toString())

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 415, 350)
        self.setWindowTitle('Calendar')
        self.show()

    def showDate(self, date):
        self.selection.setText(date.toString())

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
top = selectedDate()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's quite a lot of issues, let's work through some.

To see a window, you need to call `QWidget.show()`. Here you only call `self.show()` in `myCal` method. But `myCal` is only called with a mouse click. Surely you want to display the window right after starting the application. To do that you can simply put `self.show()` at the end of the `__init__` method.

```
class SelectedDate(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        # layout stuff, QLineEdit, etc
        self.show() # show your first window with the QLineEdit
```

---

Next, the mouse press event. The method `mousePressEvent` is actually never called! You can check that by adding a print statement in it.
It should be called when a `MouseButtonPress` is detected (in `eventFilter`)

---

Finally the calendar widget. We want to open it in a new window (`QCalendarWidget` doesn't open as a pop up by default, you need to do it yourself).

```
def myCal(self):
    self.cal = QCalendarWidget(self)
    self.cal.setGridVisible(True)
    self.cal.clicked[QDate].connect(self.showDate)

    # create a new window that contains the calendar
    self.calendarWindow = QWidget()
    hbox = QHBoxLayout()
    hbox.addWidget(self.cal)
    self.calendarWindow.setLayout(hbox)
    self.calendarWindow.setGeometry(300, 300, 415, 350)
    self.calendarWindow.setWindowTitle('Calendar')
    # open this new window
    self.calendarWindow.show()
```

---

Now some more advice. You should start by a simple app and build more functionality when it works. Writing a lot of code for only a blank window it not a good idea! So if you where to do this again, work by steps:

- Show a window with a `QLineEdit` (write code, test that it works)
- Implement the event filter (use print statements to see if it works)
- Implement opening a new blank window when clicking the `QLineEdit`
- Fill that blank window with the calendar
- Connect the calendar to the `QLineEdit` text (that code was good by the way)

Also, you can use better variable names, some suggestions:

- `selectedDate` -> `SelectDateWidget`
- `selection` -> `date_selection`
- `mousePressEvent` -> `on_date_selection_clicked`
- `myCal` -> `open_calendar`
- `cal` -> `calendar`
- `showDate` -> `on_calendar_clicked` or `update_date_selection_text`

Comment: Thanks a lot, Mel. I'll go over your suggestions and let you know how it goes.